# Django3.2 связь OneToOneField на related_name object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django, база-данных, orm, атрибуты

У меня проблема с получением данных через related_name, он не может найти атрибут  all(). =(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с тем же, так как у тебя связь OneToOne для получения объекта ты должен использовать просто related_name.

В твоем случае - type.types